# How to use a Postrgrex extension to handle JSON data type

Tags: elixir, ecto

The Postgrex project page mentions the ability to use extensions to encode/decode types coming from the db https://github.com/ericmj/postgrex#extensions

I'm trying to get the code from the project page to return a map, but I'm not sure where the extension is supposed to hook into Postgrex, if it matters, I'm attempting to do so in a Phoenix web app:

```
defmodule Extensions.JSON do
  alias Postgrex.TypeInfo

  @behaviour Postgrex.Extension

  def matching,
    do: [type: "json"]

  def format,
    do: :binary

  def encode(%TypeInfo{type: "json"}, map, _types),
    do: Poison.encode!(map)

  def decode(%TypeInfo{type: "json"}, json, _types),
    do: Poison.decode!(json)
end

#in iex
iex(5)> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query Rocket.Repo, ~s(select '{"troy":"is cool"}'::json),[]
09:51:53.423 [debug] select '{"troy":"is cool"}'::json (1.3ms)
%{columns: ["json"], command: :select, num_rows: 1,
  rows: [{"{\"troy\":\"is cool\"}"}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at [Ecto types](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the latest "master" version of Postgrex.  You can do this in your `mix.exs` by specifying `{:postgrex, git: "git://github.com/ericmj/postgrex.git"}`

Then, you have to add the extensions to your connection opts, like so:

```
{:ok, pid} = Postgrex.Connection.start_link(database: "postgres", extensions: [Extensions.JSON])
```

Hope this helps!